# Nest array into new object with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I know this one should be easy but it has me stumped. I am looking to take the following json example:

```
    [{
        "Name": "Test1",
        "Version": "5.0.1",
        "source": "source"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Test2",
        "Version": "2.0.11",
        "source": "source"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Test3",
        "Version": "2.1.2",
        "source": "source"
    }]
```

and convert it to:

```
 {
    "packages": [
        {
            "Name": "Test1",
            "Version": "5.0.1",
            "source": "source"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Test2",
            "Version": "2.0.11",
            "source": "source"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Test3",
            "Version": "2.1.2",
            "source": "source"
        }
    ]
  }
```

I've tried numerous different ways, the closest I got is using something similar to: `jq '.packages += [input]'`

Basically it's just moving the original JSON to be nested. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you tag this as `[javascript]`? The other tags you added suggest something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this

```
jq '{ packages : . }' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Even things you think of as literals are really filters in `jq`. The filter you need in this case is simply `{packages: .}`:

```
$ echo '[{}, {}]' | jq '{packages: .}'
{
  "packages": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```